# Infinispan EmbeddedCacheManager with non-clustered mode

Tags: infinispan, infinispan-9, infinispan-8

Is it possible to run embedded infinispan with non-clustered mode?

I have searched alot but could not find support for SimpleCache with EmbeddedCacheManager.

Is there a way to run embedded infinispan with local mode?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked this part of the documentation? It might be what you need.
http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#which_cache_mode_should_i_use
http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#simple_cache
http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/09/simple-cache.html

Comment: Yes, I have gone through all 3 links. It is mentioned in 3rd link that Simple cache is not compatible with embedded and server modes and it also does not support persistence, which is required in my case as I have to deal with large data.

I want to run embedded infinispan without any cluster node i.e. in local mode, but DefaultCacheManager by default creates cluster node on cache start.

see start API  : https://www.javatips.net/api/infinispan-master/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/manager/DefaultCacheManager.java

Comment: By default, the cluster mode in the configuration is LOCAL, which means there is no cluster. `DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager();
      cacheManager.defineConfiguration("toto", new ConfigurationBuilder().build());
      Cache<String, String> totoCache = cacheManager.getCache("toto");

      totoCache.put("k", "v");

      System.out.println(totoCache.get("k"));

      cacheManager.stop();`